# Passing a url from a link drag-and-dropped from InternetExplorer to sojamo/Processing

Tags: java, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, protected-mode

I'm having trouble dropping an address from the IE address bar into a processing application, even the simple DropBasics.pde example that comes with [sDrop](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/drop/). I think the problem is to do with Internet Explorer's Protected Mode. There's an informative article on MSDN about [Allowing Drag and Drop Operations in your Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#wpm_addya) but I cannot work out even simple settings for a processing app. For instance the example registry setting in that article is

> AppName="contose.exe"
>
> AppPath="C:\%USERPROFILE%\ApplicationData\Contoso"
>
> Policy=(DWORD) 00000003

but the running exe for processing is javaw and the following doesn't seem to work

> AppName=javaw.exe
>
> AppPath=C:\Windows\SysWOW64
>
> Policy=dword:00000003

Has anyone had any success registering Processing applications to accept links dropped from the IE address bar? If so how is it done?